# sinon.stub().returns specified for each call rather then once

Tags: javascript, testing, promise, sinon

Below I have a bit of code to demonstrate how I am testing / stubbing a promise, the function below `useSpyPromise` uses the argument promise `spyPromise`. Im trying to figure out how I can specify the stub to return one promise on the first call (`Promise.resolve(['hasLength']`) and the a different promise resolved on the second call (`Promise.resolve([]`).

```
let spyPromise = sinon.stub().returns(Promise.resolve(['hasLength']))

function useSpyPromise (spyPromise) {
  let promiseOne = spyPromise
    .then(d => {
      if (d.length === 0) throw new Error('d 0')
      return d
    })

  let promiseTwo = spyPromise
    .then(d => {
      if (d.length === 1) throw new Error('d 1')
      return d
    })

  return {promiseOne, promiseTwo}  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell exactly what you want but one thing seems pretty certain; providing the tests are synchronous - ie. no further promises are involved - then you don't need `promise1` and `promise2`, just `return spyPromise.then(...)`.

You may just want the behaviour to be determined entirely by `d.length`, in which case it's as simple as :

```
function useSpyPromise(spyPromise) {
    return spyPromise.then(d => {
        if(d.length <= 1) {
            throw new Error('d ' + d.length);
        }
        return d;
    });
}
```

However, if you genuinely want the number of times the function is called to be taken into account, then maybe something like this :

```
var count = 0;
function useSpyPromise(spyPromise) {
    count += 1;
    return spyPromise.then(d => {
        if(count === 0 && d.length === 0) {
            throw new Error('d 0');
        if(count === 1 && d.length === 1) {
            throw new Error('d ' + d.length);
        }
        return d;
    });
}
```

That's a pretty weird thing to want but maybe it's what your application requires. I can't tell.

Either way, that's not the end of the story. You could formulate the tests in any number of ways. For example should a `count > 1` condition throw? The question doesn't say so, but have you considered those cases?

What you write depends on the precise behaviour you want.